# How can I install Z36xxx/Z37xxx audio drivers for arch linux?

Tags: arch-linux, drivers, audio, intel, hp

I have installed Arch Linux, the necessary WIFI drivers, and the XFCE desktop environment on my HP Stream 14. However, I am not able to turn on the audio for videos. I have tried clicking on the sound icon at the top of the screen, and it gives me the following error:
`Failed to execute child process pavucontrol (No such file or directory).`
I also tried pressing the mute/unmute key on my physical keyboard, and it does nothing. I believe this is a problem with my audio drivers, however I haven't installed any because I don't know which ones to install.
The output of the command `lspci` in terminal is

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0e)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx, Celeron N2000 Series USB xHCI (rev 0e)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 0e)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 0e)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 0e)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 0e)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev 0e)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Power Control Unit (rev 0e)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series SMBus Controller (rev 0e)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

Is this a problem with my WIFI drivers? If so, How do I fix it? What command should I use to install them?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like your system is configured to use pulseaudio. Is the pulseaudio daemon running? Did you try installing `pavucontrol`?

Comment: I have just installed it. Now it says, ```Establishing connection to PulseAudio. Please wait...```. I have been waiting for 15 minutes.

Comment: Oh nevermind, I just had to run ```pulseaudio --start```. Thanks!